# Show that the expected value of $X$ is $E(X)=\frac{n+1}{2}$ when $X\sim DU(n)$

Tags: probability, self-study

The function is given as $f(x)=P(X=x) =\frac{1}{n}$ for $x=1,2,...,n$, and $0$ otherwise. Does this mean $E(X) = \sum_{x=1}^n p_nx_n$ with $\frac{1}{n} + \frac{2}{n} +\frac{3}{n} +...+\frac{n}{n} = 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$P(X=x)=\frac{1}{n}$ is constant as $x$ varies from $1$ to $n$ ... you have it changing.

e.g. consider the outcome of rolling a fair six-sided die. The probabilities are $\{\frac16,\frac16,\frac16,\frac16,\frac16,\frac16\}$ not $\{\frac11,\frac12,\ldots\frac16\}$. That doesn't even sum to $1$.

Fix that and try again. Be careful with your notation

Edit: ... to respond to your followup question and edit to the question, $\:\frac{1}{n}(1+2+3+...+n)\mathbf{\neq} 1$. The expression for the expectation has the increasing contributions from the successive terms, and doesn't equal 1. The probability has constant terms and does total 1.

Comment: I can factor out an $n$ and I get to $\frac{1}{n}(1+2+3+...+n)=1$ I am still perplexed on what to do next

Comment: @Lanous $\:\frac{1}{n}(1+2+3+...+n)\mathbf{\neq} 1$

Comment: $(1+2+...+n)=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

Comment: @DeepNorth I was attempting to follow [our guidelines in relation to homework](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) which are to offer hints and guidance; I was avoiding stating it directly on purpose (because once you state it, there's only two $n$'s to cancel, leaving essentially nothing for the OP to do). I imagine the OP likely knows this fact as well, but simply needed to think more carefully.